# Ayuda con pase de referencia en C++?

Tags: c++

Buenas, estoy "haciendo" un juego como practica... Necesito pasarle por referencia un tipo de dato jugador a una funcion en la clase enemigo, no puedo agregarle directamente el `"jugador.h"` en el `"enemy.h"` ya que esta incluido en otro header, por eso necesito declararlo mediante `ifndef`.. aqui el codigo

```
#ifndef JUGADOR_H
#define JUGADOR_H

class Jugador;

class Enemy

{

public:

    sf::Texture texturaEnemy;
    sf::Sprite spriteEnemy;
    sf::IntRect rectEnemy;
    sf::Clock clock, frame;
    sf::Time time;
    sf::Text vidaTexto;
    sf::Font vidaFuente;
    bool repetir = true;
    bool movimiento = true;
    int speed = 50;
    int orientacion = 0;
    int balas = 0;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float delta;

public:
    Enemy();

    void Inicializar();
    void EnemyMovement(Jugador &jugador);
    void Movement();
    void EnemyDraw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    void Collision(Jugador &jugador);
    void UpdateEnemy(sf::RenderWindow &window, Jugador &jugador);
};

#endif
```

como podran ver use `#ifndef` para incluir la clase jugador, mas abajo verán los metodos de la clase `enemy` a la cual estoy pasando por referencia el tipo de dato jugador `&jugador`, y aqui es donde tengo el problema:

```
    void Enemy::EnemyMovement(Jugador &jugador) {

        time = clock.restart();
        delta = time.asSeconds();

        int diferenciaX = spriteEnemy.getPosition().x - error;

        if (diferenciaX > -1 && diferenciaX < 1) {
            movimiento = true;
        }
        else {
            movimiento = false;
        }

        if (spriteEnemy.getPosition().y < error && movimiento) {
            rectEnemy.top = 0;
            spriteEnemy.setPosition(spriteEnemy.getPosition().x, spriteEnemy.getPosition().y + speed * delta);
            if (frame.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.2f) {
                Movement();
            }
        }
```

a la hora de escribir jugador.  no me sale las variables que tengo en la clase jugador para poder modificarlas desde este metodo... si alguien sabe por favor gracias

Answer (score 1):

> no puedo agregarle directamente el "jugador.h" en el "enemy.h" ya que esta incluido en otro header

La cabecera no necesita conocer la implementación de `Jugador` ya que la clase `Enemy`:

- no tiene una variable miembro de tipo `Jugador`.
- no tiene funciones `inline` que accedan a funciones o variables de la clase `Jugador`.
- no hereda de `Jugador`

Luego la *declaration forward* que haces en `"enemy.h"` es un ejemplo de cómo se deberían hacer las cosas en C++.

Sin embargo, en el cpp necesitas acceder a funciones de `Jugador` y eso es lo que te está dando problemas... la solución es tan sencilla como poner:

```
#include "jugador.h"
```

... en `"enemy.cpp"`.

El cpp no va a sufrir el problema de cruce de includes de la cabecera ya que nadie incluye un cpp en otro, así que en los cpp no debería haber problemas a la hora de poner tantos includes como sean necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en cada .h pongas el ifndef correspondiente.

Profesionalmente siempre se hace así, cada .h empieza por #ifndef ....

Lo sé, esto es un "boilerplate" que te cagas, pero todo el mundo lo hace así.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code#Preamble

Asi podras incluir sin problemas donde quieras...

Y para empezar, cambia JUGADOR_H por ENEMY_H en el archivo enemy.h, para que no haya confusiones....

Comment: No se si te has fijado pero su cabecera ya empieza por `#ifndef` ...

Comment: Su cabecera empieza por un #ifndef INCORRECTO (debe ser ENEMY_H) y el falta otro #ifndef en el otro fichero .h.

Comment: Eso que dices puede ser así o no, no sabes si es el caso o si es que no te quiere enseñar la clase `Jugador` y por eso lo ha dejado como un *declaration forward*. En C++ no hay nada que te impida declarar / implementar varias clases en un mismo archivo